EAS ios Build: Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed
I am having trouble building my first ios app. I have gone ahead an purchased a developer account, as I instructed by the previous error. Now, I am getting this error and have no notifications of statements I need to agree to when I log into my apple account. I have noticed some questions with similar looking questioning but when I read them, they were experiencing different issues. Some help would be appreciated.
› Saving Apple ID password to the local Keychain
  Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/security#keychain
× Logging in...
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
Need to acknowledge to Apple's Apple ID and Privacy statement. Please manually log into https://appleid.apple.com (or https://appstoreconnect.apple.com) to acknowledge the statement.
    Error: build command failed.

